# Inset not working uniformly even after applying rotation and scale

Tags: faces

[image]

I'm trying to inset uniformly but even after applying rotation and scale to the object it deforms when I inset. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: it seems like the starting frame is a polygon so I wouldnt expect a perfect square inset. Try to convert it to a quad first.

Comment: I'm a little confused. They are quads at the start. What do you mean?

Comment: The original face has 6 edges: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTIsP.jpg or you are insetting 2 quad faces... I don't know what you are starting from